# Replacing one character in a multiple-lined pattern with Sed

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I have a file with a boolean value set for a file location that appears on the next line.  I need to change the 'delete' value to 1 for all filepaths that include 'trash' in them.  I am trying to use sed for this task.

I am having difficulty getting the pattern references (ie. \1 ) to output properly

Please see the file sample below:

```
delete: 0
filepath: Downloads/trash/foo1
delete: 0
filepath: Downloads/keep/foobar
delete: 0
filepath: Downloads/trash/foofoofoo
```

This is what I have for sed function.  I am trying to catch the second line to be reference by \1 later but it outputs as just '1'.

```
sed -e '
/delete)/{
N
/\(.*trash.*\)/c \
delete: 1
\1
}' test.txt > test2.txt
```

The output:

```
delete: 1
1
delete: 0
filepath: Downloads/keep/foo1
delete: 1
2
```

I see changes in both the lines I want, so I know I'm fetching the correct lines in pattern space.  But the second line is not outputting properly. I also know this type of syntax works fine in single-line replacements, but not in this multi-line situation.

Any help would be appreciated.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/^delete/{N;/trash/s/delete: 0/delete: 1/}' file
```

This looks for lines beginning `delete` then appends the next line and looks for `trash` and if so replaces `delete: 0` with `delete: 1`

N.B. You cannot use back references in `i`, `a` or `c` commands only in `s/.../.../`
see [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Other-Commands.html#Other-Commands_http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Other-Commands.html#Other-Commands).

Comment: This worked perfectly. Thank you for the reference why as well.

Answer (score 2):

sed is the wrong tool to use on any problem that involves multiple lines. That's what awk is for:

```
$ awk '!(NR%2){print "delete:", (/trash/?1:0) ORS $0}' file
delete: 1
filepath: Downloads/trash/foo1
delete: 0
filepath: Downloads/keep/foobar
delete: 1
filepath: Downloads/trash/foofoofoo
```

or if your existing delete value might be non-zero for other reasons:

```
$ awk 'NR%2{d=$NF;next} {print "delete:", (/trash/?1:d) ORS $0}' file
delete: 1
filepath: Downloads/trash/foo1
delete: 0
filepath: Downloads/keep/foobar
delete: 1
filepath: Downloads/trash/foofoofoo
```

Comment: This did work for me with the few lines included in my question.  But my file had some other lines in it that I did not include.  Potong's solution handled the unexpected input as well.  Thank you for the working awk example.  It's clearly something I need to get familiar with.

Comment: Yeah, if your posted sample input doesn't reflect the real input then certainly YMMV with the answers you get. Had you shown an input file with different lines I would have posted a slightly different solution. Oh well.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ sed -i '$!N;s/^delete: 0\(\nfilepath:.*\/trash\/.*\)$/delete 1\1/i;P;D' test.txt
delete 1
filepath: Downloads/trash/foo1
delete: 0
filepath: Downloads/keep/foobar
delete 1
filepath: Downloads/trash/foofoofoo
$
```